# Better solution for problem $\sin x = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

While going through `trignometric equations` I came around the problem

`sin(x) = 1/2`

According to what I have learnt the solution should be

[image]

But beside this I also found following as the solution

[image] where n belongs to `Z`

I know both these are correct, but I want to know which should I consider more proper (like if I want to write a code that solves this problem which output should I consider)

Not only this but other such problem that involve `sine` have such thing.

Comment: It is a bit obscure to spot these give equivalent solutions.  From a coding standpoint the second description seems more natural to me, but that may not be a widely shared opinion.  In any event if I wanted to use the first description as implementation (for eldgance?), I'd consider it worthy of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution can be anyone. 

Because the values you have chosen are equivalent to each other, means both are the same solutions.

---

$$2n\pi + \frac{5\pi}{6} = 2n\pi + \pi - \frac{\pi}{6} = k\pi - \frac{\pi}{6} $$
And 
$$2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{6} = k\pi + \frac{\pi}{6}$$

Comment: but I guess by substituting different values of n in the second type of solution we could get all possible answers which we could get from the first type of solution.

Comment: @Sagar Mishra:  The second solution set is equivalent to the first.  I.e., you're wrong when you called the second solution is a subset of the first.  Or I should say, the second solution presented is not a proper subset of the first, but is equivalent to the first.

Comment: Indeed: for all $k \in \mathbb Z$ when $k$ is even, $$\sin\left(k\pi + \frac \pi6\right) = \frac 12$$ and when $k$ is odd $$\sin \left(k\pi - \frac{\pi}6\right) = \frac 12$$

Answer (score 0):

The solution of $\sin { x } =a\\ $ are $$\begin{cases} { x }_{ 1 }=\arcsin { a } +2\pi n \\ { x }_{ 2 }=\pi -\arcsin { a } +2\pi n \end{cases}$$ but you can write it  in different form as you have  mentioned$$\begin{cases} { x }_{ 1 }=\arcsin { a } +2\pi n \\ { x }_{ 2 }=-\arcsin { a } +\left( 2\pi +1 \right) n \end{cases}\Rightarrow { x }_{ 1,2 }={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ n }\arcsin { a } +\pi n,n\in Z$$